# How to replace the using pattern in specialization for template template argument

Tags: c++

I have this chunk of code that is a common pattern to do template specialization. To remove the requirement of specifying `DataType1` for `Processor1<DataType1>` in the first line of main function, I want to receive a template template argument instead. Looks like the `using` directive does not support assigning an "open" template argument and I'm unable to find any example of that in the web (maybe I'm not searching with the appropriate keywords...)

```
#include <iostream>

struct DataType1 {};
struct DataType2 {};

template<class TDataType>
struct BaseMessage{ using DataType = TDataType; };

template<class TDataType>
struct ChildMessage : public BaseMessage<TDataType> {};

template<class TDataType>
struct Processor1 {
    static void func() { std::cout << "Processor1" << std::endl; }
};

template<class TDataType>
struct Processor2 {
    static void func() { std::cout << "Processor2" << std::endl; }
};

template<class TResult>
struct FindDefaultProcessor;

template<>
struct FindDefaultProcessor<DataType1>
{
    using type = Processor1;
};

template<class TResult, template<class> class TProcessor = FindDefaultProcessor<TResult>::type>
void func()
{
    TProcessor<typename TResult::DataType>::func();
}

int main()
{
    func<ChildMessage<DataType2>, Processor1>();
    return 0;
}
```

So the question is pretty "simple", how can I make this code compile? in `FindDefaultProcessor`, `using type = Processor1;` does not compile. I need a mechanism to retrieve a type that is still "open".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Processor1` is not a type, you probably mean

```
template<>
struct FindDefaultProcessor<DataType1>
{
    template <typename U>
    using type = Processor1<U>;
};
```

and you need extra keyword `template`:

```
template<class TResult,
         template<class> class TProcessor = FindDefaultProcessor<TResult>::template type>
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d60bfebcae0dd984)

Comment: Oh wow I indeed added a template<class U> but forgot to add the U to Processor1. And thank you for the fix on ::type as it requires template keyword. this syntax looks like a deep c++ secret to me :p (cannot accept the answer before 9 minutes... ok stackoverflow...)

Comment: @Sproulx This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245 covers the need for that syntax quite nicely.